# Manipulação de DataFrame no R

Tags: r

Eu tenho o dataset conforme a figura. Eu preciso nomear a coluna Mes sendo que onde for 1 é Janeiro, 2 fevereiro e assim por diante. Preciso ainda agrupar por tipo de despesa e somar o valor reembolsado. A idéia é gerar graficos mensais por nome, tipo de despesa e pelo total do valor reembolsado. Estou batendo cabeça aqui. Alguem pode me ajudar. Obrigado.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Olá Edi, o modo mais rápido de te ajudar seria se você disponibilizasse uma amostra reproduzível de seu conjunto de dados, essa imagem postada é até explicativa, mas não reproduzível, sugiro que nas próximas postagens utilize o comando `dput(dataset)`, isso facilitará e muito obter uma reposta.

Comment: Obrigado. Vou seguir a recomendação.

Answer (score 1):

Tome como exemplo hipotético esse conjunto de dados

```
Mes = c(1,2,2,4,3)
Nome = c("ACIR G","ACIR G","ACIR G","ACIR G","ACIR G")
Tipo = c("Aluguel", "Aluguel","Aluguel", "Passagem", "Passagem")
Valor = c(5, 10, 15, 20, 25)

(dataset = data.frame(Mes, Nome, Tipo, Valor))
#  Mes   Nome     Tipo Valor
#1   1 ACIR G  Aluguel     5
#2   2 ACIR G  Aluguel    10
#3   2 ACIR G  Aluguel    15
#4   4 ACIR G Passagem    20
#5   3 ACIR G Passagem    25

# tipo de dados
str(dataset)

# transformando a coluna em factor
(dataset$Mes = factor(dataset$Mes))
#[1] 1 2 2 4 3
#Levels: 1 2 3 4

# categorizando os levels da coluna 
levels(dataset$Mes) =  factor(c("Jan", "Fev", "Mar", "Abr"))
#[1] Jan Fev Mar Abr
#Levels: Abr Fev Jan Mar

library(dplyr)

# valor total por tipo 
group_by(dataset, Tipo) %>% summarise(Total = sum(Valor))
# A tibble: 2 x 2
#  Tipo     Total
#  <fct>    <dbl>
#1 Aluguel     30
#2 Passagem    45

# valor total por mês segundo o tipo 
group_by(dataset,  Mes, Tipo) %>% summarise(Total = sum(Valor))
# A tibble: 4 x 3
# Groups:   Mes [?]
#  Mes   Tipo     Total
#  <fct> <fct>    <dbl>
#1 Jan   Aluguel      5
#2 Fev   Aluguel     25
#3 Mar   Passagem    25
#4 Abr   Passagem    20
```

Comment: Olá Fernandes. Eu vou reproduzir aqui e volto para informar o resultado. Mas já deu uma clareada. Obrigado.

Comment: Olá Fernandes/Comunidade. Eu segui sua recomendação e deu super certo. Muito obrigado. A única coisa é que o resultado da soma está retornando o valor como notação cientifica: o código é: group_by(senado_acir, despesa) %>% summarise(Total = sum(gasto)) ele agrupa os tipos de despesa e soma os gastos. Até aí perfeito, porém a soma retorna uma notação cientifica tal como: 1.57e5 que seria 1.57*10^5 . Tem como transformar isso no R?

Comment: Utilize o comando `options(scipen = 15)` no início do seu script, ele irá reproduzir valores com até 15 dígitos.